# User input(cin) - Default value

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I can't figure out how to use a "default value" when asking the user for input. I want the user to be able to just press Enter and get the default value. Consider the following piece of code, can you help me?

```
int number;
cout << "Please give a number [default = 20]: ";
cin >> number;

if(???) {
// The user hasn't given any input, he/she has just 
// pressed Enter
number = 20;

}
while(!cin) {

// Error handling goes here
// ...
}
cout << "The number is: " << number << endl;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read a line of text from `std::cin`. If the line is empty, use your default value. Otherwise, use a [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to convert the given string to a number. If this conversion fails, the default value will be used.

Here's a sample program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Please give a number [default = 20]: ";

    int number = 20;
    std::string input;
    std::getline( std::cin, input );
    if ( !input.empty() ) {
        std::istringstream stream( input );
        stream >> number;
    }

    std::cout << number;
}
```

Comment: is there any way to check if user is entering a valid input(as there is in cin).
I mean, I want to detect when user enters some characters instead of just numbers and throw an error message.

Answer (score 13):

This works as an alternative to the accepted answer. I would say `std::getline` is a bit on the overkill side.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int number = 0;

    if (std::cin.peek() == '\n') { //check if next character is newline
        number = 20; //and assign the default
    } else if (!(std::cin >> number)) { //be sure to handle invalid input
        std::cout << "Invalid input.\n";
        //error handling
    }

    std::cout << "Number: " << number << '\n';    
}
```

Here's a [live sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/000e3acc53b0f8a3) with three different runs and inputs.

Comment: For what it's worth, I concur - I like your version better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!cin)
   cout << "No number was given.";
else
   cout << "Number " << cin << " was given.";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to read the line as a string using `getline()` and then you've (arguably) more control over the conversion process:

```
int number(20);
string numStr;
cout << "Please give a number [default = " << number << "]: ";
getline(cin, numStr);
number = ( numStr.empty() ) ? number : strtol( numStr.c_str(), NULL, 0);
cout << number << endl;
```