# input string to int variables in c++

Tags: c++

In C++,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int i;
    cin >> i;
    cout << i;
    return 0;
}
```

If we input a string to `i`, for example, `"integer"`, it will display 0 when cout, which means that the string becomes 0. Could it be possible to make the string become some other integer, 10000 for example?

Comment: What have you tried? Setting a number to 10,000 is something you should really try to do yourself before running to us for help.

Comment: Take a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314682/user-inputcin-default-value
Maybe it will help you out

Comment: You could build your own class `Foo`, and a global operator function for `>>` for your class and a stream. You could even build syntax to support `cin >> setFooDefault(1) >>`. Your class could even have a cast operator to `int`. That said, @PaulR's answer is more sensible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure - you can just do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int i = 10000;   // initialise i to default value
    int temp;        // temporary integer for input validation

    if (cin >> temp) // if valid integer entered
        i = temp;    // set i to entered integer (otherwise leave it at default value)
    cout << i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and test:

```
$ g++ -Wall input.cpp 
$ ./a.out
1234
1234
$ ./a.out
fred
10000
$
```

Answer (score -1):

You'd have to input it to a string variable then examine the string and work out what to do