# Default value for variable in C++ using cin >>

Tags: c++, c++11

I have written this code in C++ in the CodeBlocks IDE but when I run it, it doesn't give me -1 if it doesn't read a number, it gives me 0. Is there something wrong with the code?

```
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Please enter your first name and age:\n";
    string first_name="???"; //string variable
                            //("???" means "don't know the name")
    int age=-1; //integer variable (-1 means "don't know the age")
    cin>>first_name>>age; //read a string followed by an integer
    cout<<"Hello, " <<first_name<<" (age "<<age<<")\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `operator<<()` will set `age` to it's default value (i.e. `0` in this case) and overwrite the `-1` when it can't read a number. That's normal behavior.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You mean `operator>>`, right?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt Quote: `since c++11: If extraction fails, zero is written to value and failbit is set`

Comment: But, from the start, I'm saying that  `age=-1`,if it does not read anything it should output `-1`. Shouldn't it? @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: @Angew Oops, of course.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The behaviour of [std::basic_istream::operator>>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) has changed from C++11. Since C++11,

> If extraction fails, zero is written to value and failbit is set. If
>   extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in
>   value, std::numeric_limits::max() or std::numeric_limits::min()
>   is written and failbit flag is set.

Note that until C++11,

> If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is
>   expected), value is left unmodified and failbit is set.

You could check the result by [std::basic_ios::fail](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail) or [std::basic_ios::operator!](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!) and set the default value by yourself. Such as,

```
string first_name;
if (!(cin>>first_name)) {
    first_name = "???";
    cin.clear(); //Reset stream state after failure
}

int age;
if (!(cin>>age)) {
    age = -1;
    cin.clear(); //Reset stream state after failure
}

cout<<"Hello, " <<first_name<<" (age "<<age<<")\n";
```

See also: [Resetting the State of a Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246960/resetting-the-state-of-a-stream)

Comment: I would address OP on how to check failbit (and then set the default value). I would also point him [here: Resetting the State of a Stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246960/resetting-the-state-of-a-stream)

Comment: I think OP is more interested in setting the default value in that case. (And I would also reset the status of the stream)

Comment: Who's OP? And why when I asked a friend of mine to write the exact same code in Visual Studio 2015 it gave him `-1` if it didn't read a number? Is it something about the IDE? @songyuanyao

Comment: @Alberto **O**riginal **P**oster - the author of the question. And Visual Studio is generally quite sloppy in following the standard. It's very possible their standard library still follows C++03 behaviour in this regard.

Comment: @Alberto As Angew said, VS2015 might not support this c++11 feature yet, or you need to specify some compile option to enable it. Anyway, if you check the input result and set the default value by yourself (as the code in my answer), it will work well for both the compilers support the feature or not.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers.

Comment: I wonder how can the first cin fail, and if probably to make cin usable again you need to reset the state of the stream http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246960/resetting-the-state-of-a-stream

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for custom default values when reading from `std::cin`. You have to read the user input as a string and check if it's empty. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314682/user-inputcin-default-value) for details.

Quoting from the linked question:

```
int age = -1;
std::string input;
std::getline( std::cin, input );
if ( !input.empty() ) {
    std::istringstream stream( input );
    stream >> age;
}
```